# "Interface" for .Net Resource files

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, translation, culture

I am building a multi-language MVC application and have a series of resource files with translated strings for messages that will be displayed to the user.

Is there any way of ensuring that any resource files added in the future have all required keys and are spelled correctly?

As an analogy, if the resource file was a regular class, you could provide an interface to ensure that all required method and properties were present in the implementing class. Is there a similar concept for resource files?

Comment: I believe resource files have a default fallback value. For example, if you define the values in `Resources.resx`, then any keys missing in `Resources.es.resx` would fall back to the first file. This doesn't guarantee they will be implemented, but ensures something will be there.

Comment: A better analogy for .NET resource files would be a base class with virtual methods, that can (not must) be overridden in derived classes

Comment: @MaxHampton true, but I would still like to have some validation if possible.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque that makes more sense, however the question still stands.

Comment: Some tools like ReSharper verify that all resources are overridden in all languages (if you open the resx file in XML, not in the designer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been unable to find a supported way to enforce an explicit contract upon a `.resx` file. Since your goal is ultimately to catch implementation errors before they show up at runtime (and compile time checking isn't possible), I recommend falling back to static code analysis. Luckily, .NET makes this trivially easy:

- Use the `System.Resources.ResXResourceReader` class to read the contents of the resx files to be validated.
- Implement a test that asserts against all required keys in the "contract" you'd like to enforce on the resx.
- Test should run as part of an existing test suite, and failure will warn a developer of the implicit contract before encountering the problem at runtime.
- Since your resource files will exist in a known location, you can trivially ensure that the tests run against all resx files in that directory. In this way, you don't even need to update the test when new resource files are added, only if the contract changes.

I've used a similar approach to help with maintenance of stored procedure names kept in (an extensive number of) resx files. Since the resource files are spread across dozens of projects, manual maintenance is tedious and error-prone -- in other words, it doesn't get done. The static code analysis approach has yielded few downsides, and I think it would work well in your case as well.

- [Landing page for resource files on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekyft91f%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)
- [ResXResourceReader on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resxresourcereader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

`System.Resources.ResXResourceReader` requires a reference to `System.Windows.Forms`. It's available on both .NET and Mono.

Comment: This was what I was leaning towards. That, or have some piece of code that checks each key against a "master" list, or something that checks the XML itself. If no one comes up with another answer, I'll mark this as accepted.